# AWS RDS Performance Insights not showing SQL Server Queries

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I enabled Performance Insights on an existing SQL Server database (Express, if it matters) in AWS RDS. If I look at the database load graph and table I do not see any of the queries I am doing in real time. I see some queries that appear to be done by Amazon itself, such as selecting from rdsadmin.dbo.log_backup_manifest.

If I change the range to the past 24 hours, I see what appears to be a couple non-system queries on our actual data by another user. But I can't get any new queries to appear. I show up as a Host on the Hosts tab and as a User on the Users tab. The dashboard shows "0 sessions" even when I have SSMS open and connected to it, though.

Is there some condition I need to meet in order to have my query get recorded in Performance Insights? What's the criteria? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: same problem here